# Spring project template menu not show with springsource-tool-suite e4.6.3

Tags: sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use *eclipse neon* and download *springsource-tool-suite-3.9.0.RELEASE-e4.6.3-updatesite.zip*, after I installed it successfully no spring project menu show in new menu. How can I do with it?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of wizards to create new Spring projects included in STS 3.9.0, especially those to create new Spring Boot projects. Go to `New -> Spring Boot -> Spring Starter Project` and use that to create a new Spring Boot project (the preferred way nowadays).

In addition to that you can also use the `Import Spring Getting Started Content` to import projects from http://spring.io/guides directly into your workspace.

If you switch to the Spring perspective, you will get those wizards as shortcuts in the package explorer context menu, too.

The old and outdated "New Spring Project Template" wizard is gone for quite a while now.